# Mozilla Add-on SDK - OS.File.read (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: sdk, firefox-addon, mozilla

I created an add-on following Mozilla's tutorials. `cfx test` and `cfx run` worked perfectly. I put the folder on my desktop and installed the add-on into Firefox using `cfx xpi` and Ctrl+o (the xpi file).

Now the add-on gives this error in the console log:

> Win error 2 during operation open on file purls.txt (The system cannot
>   find the file specified.)

Here is the relevant code in main.js:

```
const {TextEncoder, TextDecoder, OS} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});
let decoder = new TextDecoder();
let promise = OS.File.read("purls.txt").then(
    function onSuccess(array) {
        // Do stuff
    },
    function onReject(reason) {
        console.error("Couldn't read from purls.txt:\n"+reason);
    }
);
```

Please help me figure out what is going on. When I use `cfx run` the add-on finds the purls.txt file and opens it/reads from it without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't give it a path to purls.txt, so it was probably looking for purls.txt on your drive. Is it on the desktop? Then create a path to the desktop. See `pathToPurls`;

```
const {TextEncoder, TextDecoder, OS} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/osfile.jsm", {});
let decoder = new TextDecoder();
let pathToPurls = OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, "purls.txt");
console.log('pathToPurls:', pathToPurls);
let promise = OS.File.read(pathToPurls).then(
    function onSuccess(array) {
        // Do stuff
    },
    function onReject(reason) {
        console.error("Couldn't read from purls.txt:\n"+reason);
    }
);
```

Comment: I think that worked because I'm not getting the error, but I'm also not seeing the console.log output in the Browser Console. I added a console.log inside the function onSuccess, and I'm not seeing that in the Browser Console either. Again, both show up when I run `cfx run`, just not after install. Is there a fix?

Comment: I take it back - it's clearly working. Thanks! I see in the documentation that console.log messages not showing up post-install is by design.

Comment: Try using console.error in the onSuccess you should see it. I dont know why addon-sdk has different log levels. it might be because people release their code with the console.log's in it which slows down performance a lot as its dumping to a log.